LilyPond - how to force C#m7(b5) instead of C#ø
I want my score to show C#m7(b5) instead of C#ø.
As per Lilypond- Half diminished Seventh symbol, I've created the following exception:
chExceptions = {
  <c ees ges b>1-\markup {"m7(" \char ##x266D "5)" }
}

and in the score section
\chords {
  \set noChordSymbol = ""
  \set chordNameExceptions = #chExceptions
  r2 e2 a2:m6/c b2:7 e4:m b4:7 e4:m cis4:m7.5-
}

but the last chord is rendered as

How do I make it render like this:


You almost got it:
\version "2.24.3"

chExceptionMusic = {
  <c ees ges bes>1-\markup { m\super \concat { 7 (\teeny\raise #.3 \flat 5) } }
}

chExceptions = #(append
  (sequential-music-to-chord-exceptions chExceptionMusic #t)
  ignatzekExceptions)

\new ChordNames \chordmode {
  \set chordNameExceptions = #chExceptions
  cis1:m7.5-
}

